# Java client socket connect doesn't work

Tags: java, node.js, sockets

So I'm trying to make a java client that can connect to a node.js server using this guide -> http://mrbool.com/communicating-node-js-and-java-via-sockets/33819. I followed all the steps, but when I ran the code, the thread blocks. I have the proper events on the nodejs server, but it's not receiving the message from my java client. Does anyone know why this happens and a fix for it?

Node.js code:

```
var net = require('net');
var host = '127.0.0.1';
var port = 3000;
var server = net.createServer((sock) => {
    console.log("Connected " + sock.remoteAddress + ":" + sock.remotePort);
    sock.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log("Received Data")
        sock.write(data);
    })

    sock.on('close', (data) => {
        console.log('CLOSED ' + sock.remoteAddress + ":" + sock.remotePort);
    });
});

server.listen(port, host);
console.log("listening on " + host + ":" + port);
```

And the Java client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class Main {
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader input;
    private PrintWriter output;
    String hostName = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 3000;
    public Main() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    try {
        main.connect();
        String message = "test123";

        System.out.println("Sending " + message);
        String returnStr = main.echo(message);
        System.out.println(returnStr);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
        main.getSocket().close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }

    public void connect() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    clientSocket = new Socket(hostName, port);
    }


    public String echo(String message) throws IOException {
    try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()); 
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));){
        String returnStr = null;
        System.out.println("Attempting to send");
        out.print(message);
        returnStr = in.readLine();
        return returnStr;
    }
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
    return clientSocket;
    }
}
```

The command prompt output:

```
listening on 127.0.0.1:3000
Connected 127.0.0.1:52572
```

Comment: You specified port 3000 but somehow connected to `Connected 127.0.0.1:52572`, the wrong port?

Comment: The Connected 127.0.0.1:52572 only appears when I run the java code, which means that it connects, but isn't sending the data.

Comment: Try using the `telnet 127.0.0.1 3000` command to see if the server is really listen to port 3000. This way you can isolate if the server code or the client is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

The 'connect' is working perfectly. The problem is elsewhere.

1. You are reading a line, with `readLine()`.
2. You aren't sending a line: you're using `print()`.
3. The Javascript server will echo whatever you send, but it doesn't close the socket until the client does.
4. The client doesn't close the socket, because it is blocked in `readLine()` waiting for the line terminator, which is never sent.

Use `println()` instead of `print()`.

Comment: I changed print to println, but the thread still blocks. My main question really should have been how to get the server to echo the println statement back.

Comment: Seems to me that it does. Maybe you need to flush the `PrintWriter` after `println()`.